# Strings wont combine - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, file, merge

Ik have the following strings in the .H file, and i want them to merge into one string at the end of the app when the have collected their data.

It wont work, why not and how must i do it correct so the data collected in these strings will be merged into one string ??

```
NSString *dataHML; 
NSString *dataHML2;
NSString *dataHML3;
NSString *dataHML4;
NSString *dataHML5;
NSString *dataHML6;
NSString *dataHMLtotal = *dataHML + *dataHML2 + *dataHML3 + *dataHML4 + *dataHML5 + *dataHML6;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *dataHtmlTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", dataHtml, dataHtml2, dataHtml3, dataHtml4,dataHtml5,dataHtml6];
```

Comment: Agreed. You can also use "[myString stringByAppendingString:myOtherString]" if you only need to combine two strings.

Comment: no, sorry i need to merge 6 string outputs. So the above worked but i get the following error: NSString may not respond to '+dataHMLTotal:'

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C does not support operator overloading so + doesn't do what you want here. You can use:
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", dataHtml, dataHtml2, dataHtml3, dataHtml4, dataHtml5, dataHtml6];`

instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But i'm getting a compiler error with this : NSString may not respond to '+dataHMLTotal:'